# Pandas cannot read same json files saved in sub-folder

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 5 json files saved in my  current working directory, and the following code works fine for me to read each of them for further analysis:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
path=os.path.join('.') #Just want to as an example here
allfiles = os.listdir(path)
files = [files for files in allfiles if files.endswith('.json')]

for i in files:
    df=pd.read_json(i)
allfiles
```

But when I create a sub-folder in my current working directory, and move my 5 json files to it, then I cnanot read them:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
path=os.path.join('.','Result')#New Folder:Result
allfiles = os.listdir(path)
files = [files for files in allfiles if files.endswith('.json')]

for i in files:
    df=pd.read_json(i)
allfiles
```

The error message is: **ValueError: Trailing data**
I try to search it via google, but still don't know what is going on, i didn't change anything, just create a sub-folder.

Comment: In your code you have not told `pandas` to look inside the sub-directory. The output of `os.listdir(path)` does not contain the path.

Comment: my path is '.' right? because os.listdir('.') gives me all files in my current working dirct, thanks

Comment: In other words if you have a file `./Result/a.json` then you are running  `df=pd.read_json("a.json")` which will not work.

Comment: I understand no matter what I did above, [files for files in allfiles if files.endswith('.json')] gives me for example a list of file name: ['a.json']; but if I didn't include the path, we I call read_json, it will search for this file in my CWD, but not the result folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When opening the file using pandas you are passing only the filename not the absolute path. so when script is running from current directory where file is present it is able to open it.
but when you have moved the files to Result directory it is still searching for file in current directory.

edited below code to have full directory path in filenames array.

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
path=os.path.join(cwd) #Just want to as an example here
allfiles = os.listdir(path)
files = [os.path.join(path,files) for files in allfiles if files.endswith('.json')]
print(files)

for f in files :
    df1 = pd.read_json(f)
print(df1.head(1))
```

> ['C:\Users\XXX\XXX\XXX\all_data.json']
>
> glossary 
>    GlossDiv  {'title': 'S', 'GlossList': {'GlossEntry':
>   {'I...

---

```
path=os.path.join(cwd,'Result') #Just want to as an example here
allfiles = os.listdir(path)
files = [os.path.join(path,files) for files in allfiles if files.endswith('.json')]
print(files)
for f in files :
    df1 = pd.read_json(f)
print(df1.head(1))
```

> ['C:\Users\XXX\XXX\XXX\Result\all_data1.json']
>
> glossary GlossDiv  {'title': 'S', 'GlossList': {'GlossEntry': {'I...

sample data in file :

```
 {
        "glossary": {
            "title": "example glossary",
            "GlossDiv": {
                "title": "S",
                "GlossList": {
                    "GlossEntry": {
                        "ID": "SGML",
                        "SortAs": "SGML",
                        "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                        "Acronym": "SGML",
                        "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                        "GlossDef": {
                            "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                            "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                        },
                        "GlossSee": "markup"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: &Rishi Bansal mentioned I can get the cwd via os.getcwd(), and create my path via: os.path.join(wd,'Result'); i think it is looks good, but it still gives me error

Comment: I understand no matter what I did above, [files for files in allfiles if files.endswith('.json')] gives me for example a list of file name: ['json_test.json']; but if I didn;t include the path, we I call read_json, it will search for this file in my CWD, but not the result folder

Comment: @Frank I have edited my answer to include cwd, also tried on sample json it is working for me, what error you are getting now?

Comment: I pass the: files = [os.path.join(path,files) for files in allfiles if files.endswith('.json')], and this is working

Comment: Yes, ,my path here is cwd+folder

Answer (score 2):

Try Current working directory and then join the new sub directory.

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
path=os.path.join(cwd,'Result')#New Folder:Result
```

I just tested the code on .pdf as I am having pdf in Downloads directory.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
path=os.path.join(cwd,"Downloads")#New Folder:Result
allfiles = os.listdir(path)
files = [files for files in allfiles if files.endswith('.pdf')]

for i in files:
    print i
```

It worked for me.

Comment: my path is '.' right? os.listdir('.') gives your all files in my current working dirct

Comment: but when you try to join "." with other string not sure how it will behave.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob), which returns a list of paths that match your `pathname`:

```
import glob
pathname = 'Result/*.json'
list_of_paths_to_files = glob.glob(pathname)
```

If you want to read the files as many separate `DataFrame`:

```
list_of_dataframes = [pd.read_json(file_path) for file_path in list_of_paths_to_files]
```

If you want one `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes)
```